# Deploying Blazor PWA to server folder, I get errors saying that various files cannot be found

Tags: html, progressive-web-apps, blazor

I can deploy to the root of a server (e.g. http://localhost:8008) but I can't deploy to a subfolder (e.g. http://edkolis.com/pwaexperiment/wwwroot/index.html); I get errors loading various files when I try that. Files that are missing include app.css and blazor.webassembly.js:

```
<link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
```

I see there is a `<base>` tag in the index.html that specifies that all relative URLs should point to the server root:

```
<base href="/" />
```

however if I remove this tag I still get the same errors. How can I deploy my Blazor PWA to a subfolder and have it work, and yet also have it work at the root for local testing (i.e. I don't want to hardcode a server URL into the `<base>` tag)?

Comment: How did you deploy?  Did you use Publish or something else? Is the wwwroot\framework folder there?   Do you use a web.config?

Answer (score 2):

The base href must match the actual path you deploy to.

To avoid changing it build-time, update the launchsettings JSON with that folder name so local (dev) runs also use the"production" base path

Comment: Wouldn't that cause things to get out of sync - e.g. if I make a change to the CSS and then I want to test it before deploying it, I'll not get to see that change because it's pointing to the last deployed version?

Comment: I meant the folder portion only so the base urls match, something like this in your launchSettings.json -> "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:54402/some-folder/enother-folder/", and in index.html soething like -> <base href="/some-folder/enother-folder/" />